# Google Sheets: Function which will return the closest row to a specific date for each customer in a database

Tags: google-sheets

I'm not sure if this is a pipedream, but I'm looking for a formula which I can insert into a sheet to pull the earliest and latest submission for each customer from a dataset. I have included a sample dataset.

Essentially, it will match the lowest date that is between two given dates. It will return the *Submission* and *Date* from **All Submissions** that has the closest date above H1 in that sheet and matches the *Customer* number in Column A in **Earliest** sheet.

I have been trying to use something along the lines of:

```
=INDEX(All Submissions!C:C, MATCH(1,(MIN(ABS(All Submissions!D:D-All Submissions!$H$1))*(A2=All Submissions!B:B)), 0),0)
```

Sorry if this makes no sense.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: There is no sample dataset. Please include a link to a spreadsheet with some realistic data already entered as well as some hand-entered expected results where you'd like to see them.

Comment: Hi @ErikTyler, thank you for reminding me. I've added it here https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1_Dz7_lWtsyfV_OaAqVU3N9oBS0nZku_Atq-nwQoIfpI/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: It seems volunteer contributor "Daniele" is helping you. If that answer meets your needs, please be sure to mark his answer post as "Best Answer." If not, please explain what is lacking (both in a reply to this comment and in the comments section below the post by Daniele), and this may invite additional input. But at a glance, it looks to me like Daniele's solution should work for you.

Answer (score 0):

I believe this formula is right for you.
This formula gives you both the oldest and the most recent of the dates within the H1:H2 range:

```
=query(B1:D, "select B, min(D),max(D) where 
D > date '"& TEXT(H1,"yyyy-mm-dd") & "'
and D < date '" & TEXT(H2,"yyyy-mm-dd") & "'
group by B",1)
```

(*I have updated your file*)

Comment: Thank you! That looks great but do you know if it would be possible to pull the submission value associated with that date for each customer as well?

Comment: Look at the resul of the modified formula. Give me an example of what you would like to get, do it on another sheet of the file